# ORC stripe size inconsistency across stripes in a spark generated ORC file

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, orc

We are using Spark 1.6 (Cloudera 5.8.2). We use below command to generate ORC output.

```
dataframe.write().format("orc").save("spark_orc_output");
```

On one of the output file, we ran hive --orcfiledump . It shows there are 196 Stripes in that output file. Data size of each stripe varies between 19KB-19MB.

As per our understanding, stripe size is driven by some property (orc.stripe.size, hive.exec.orc.default.stripe.size), which is a constant in the application.
So,

1. Why do we see this variation in data size?
2. What is the default stripe size in Spark ORC?

[image]

Comment: ORC stripe size is a **ceiling**, it means "when current stripe has reached size X, then start a new one".  So the last stripe can contain as little as one row. And if the final ORC file was built by *concatenating* multiple temp ORC files, then every stripe might have been a last stripe at some point. Cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTable/PartitionConcatenate for the way to concatenate in Hive; maybe Spark uses the same trick under the covers, to merge the result from mutiple tasks?!

Comment: You can inspect the source code here https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/orc >> Spark does not set any specific property, except for compression.